Outlook calendar event description when sync with local calendar of Android mobile and fetch it shows in HTML formatted Text in custom app
When I fetch local calendar data in android app in the cusrosr events description data shows as HTM formatted. While creating an outlook calendar event added " This is test message " this is simple text. but from cursor getting the description data in HTML format.
When fetching local calendar data specifically calendar event description part : it should show the  data as entered like plain text and not formatted to HTML text.
